# More like this query across types with different field names?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search

Can a more like this query be used to search across types with different field names?  For example, suppose I have two different types (e.g. type1 and type2), both of which have a text field, but which have different names (e.g. type1_text and type2_text).  The following query does not produce any results:

```
GET /index-name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "fields" : ["type2_text"],
            "like" : [
            {
                "_index" : "index-name",
                "_type" : "type1",
                "_id" : "1",
                "fields": ["type1_text"]
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

(It does work if I change my mappings to use the same field names in both types.)

Is there any way to do cross-field comparisons in Elasticsearch?